# SPARQL error attempt to attach a filter with used variable

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to extract information about 2 genes at the same time using this query:

```
BASE <http://www.southgreen.fr/agrold/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX vocab:<vocabulary/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?gene ?gene_lbl ?pathway 
WHERE{
  VALUES ?gene {<http://identifiers.org/ensembl.plant/BGIOSGA000040>
                <http://identifiers.org/ensembl.plant/Sb01g003700.1>}
  {
    GRAPH ?graph1{
          OPTIONAL{?gene rdfs:label ?gene_lbl.}
    }
  }
  UNION
  {
    GRAPH ?graph2{
          OPTIONAL{?gene vocab:is_agent_in ?pathway.}
    }
  }
}
```

but it gives me the following error :

> Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Internal error: sparp_gp_attach_filter_cbk(): attempt to attach a filter with used variable

It work without problems when I run it using only one gene OR when I remove the `OPTIONAL` keyword, can someone explain to me the reason behind this behaviour ?

- Endpoint Virtuoso version: [07.10.3211](http://volvestre.cirad.fr:8080/agrold/sparqleditor.jsp#query=PREFIX++bif%3A++%3Cbif%3A%3E%0A%0ASELECT%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_dbms_name')++++++++++AS+%3Fname+)%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_dbms_ver')+++++++++++AS+%3Fversion+)%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_build_date')+++++++++AS+%3Fbuild_date+)%0A%0A%23%23+++The+following+line+must+be+commented+for+execution+on+%0A%23%23+++builds+produced+before+the+switch+from+%60cvs%60+to+%60git%60%3B%0A%23%23+++it+only+works+on+versions+later+than+v6.1.5%0A%0A%23+(+bif%3Asys_stat('git_head')++++++++++++++AS+%3Fgit_head+)+++%0A%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_build_thread_model')+AS+%3Fthread+)%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_build_opsys_id')+++++AS+%3Fopsys+)%0A%0A%23%23+++The+following+two+lines+must+be+commented+for+execution+%0A%23%23+++on+VOS%3B+these+only+work+on+Enterprise+Edition%0A%0A%23+(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_lic_owner')++++++++++AS+%3Fowner+)%0A%23+(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_lic_serial_number')++AS+%3Fserial+)%0A%0AWHERE%0A++%7B++%3Fs++%3Fp++%3Fo++%7D%0ALIMIT+1%0A)

**EDIT** :

Part of the complexity is due to the fact that this is just a sample of a bigger query.

[@TallTed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241164/tallted), thank you for you answer, when I apply your proposed method to extract more information I don't get the desired results. for instance [in this example](http://volvestre.cirad.fr:8080/agrold/sparqleditor.jsp#query=BASE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.southgreen.fr%2Fagrold%2F%3E%0APREFIX+rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX+vocab%3A%3Cvocabulary%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fgene+%3Fgene_lbl%0A%09%09%09%09%3Ftaxon+%3Ftaxon_lbl+%0A%09%09%09%09%3Fpathway+%3Fpathway_lbl%0A%09%09%09%09%3Fprotein+%3Fprot_lbl%0AWHERE%0A++%7B%0A++++VALUES+%3Fgene+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FSb01g003700.1%3E%0A++%09%09%09%09+++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FOB12G15100%3E+%7D%0A++%0A++%09OPTIONAL%7B%3Fgene++rdfs%3Alabel++%3Fgene_lbl+%7D%0A++%0A++++OPTIONAL%7B+%0A++++%09%3Fgene++vocab%3Ataxon+%3Ftaxon.%0A++++%09%3Ftaxon+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Ftaxon_lbl.%0A+%09%7D%0A++%0A++%09OPTIONAL%7B+%0A++++%09%3Fgene++vocab%3Ais_agent_in++%3Fpathway.%0A++++%09%3Fpathway+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fpathway_lbl.%0A++%09%7D%0A++%0A++%09OPTIONAL%7B+%0A++++%09%3Fgene+vocab%3Aencodes+%3Fprotein.%0A+++%09%09%3Fprotein+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fprot_lbl.%0A++%09%7D%0A%7D%0A) gene `OB12G15100` encodes a protein, but it doesn't show up in the results unless if [I comment the OPTIONAL of gene_lbl](http://volvestre.cirad.fr:8080/agrold/sparqleditor.jsp#query=BASE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.southgreen.fr%2Fagrold%2F%3E%0APREFIX+rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX+vocab%3A%3Cvocabulary%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fgene+%3Fgene_lbl%0A%09%09%09%09%3Ftaxon+%3Ftaxon_lbl+%0A%09%09%09%09%3Fpathway+%3Fpathway_lbl%0A%09%09%09%09%3Fprotein+%3Fprot_lbl%0AWHERE%0A++%7B%0A++++VALUES+%3Fgene+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FSb01g003700.1%3E%0A++%09%09%09%09+++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FOB12G15100%3E+%7D%0A++%0A++%09%23OPTIONAL%7B%3Fgene++rdfs%3Alabel++%3Fgene_lbl+%7D%0A++%0A++++OPTIONAL%7B+%0A++++%09%3Fgene++vocab%3Ataxon+%3Ftaxon.%0A++++%09%3Ftaxon+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Ftaxon_lbl.%0A+%09%7D%0A++%0A++%09OPTIONAL%7B+%0A++++%09%3Fgene++vocab%3Ais_agent_in++%3Fpathway.%0A++++%09%3Fpathway+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fpathway_lbl.%0A++%09%7D%0A++%0A++%09OPTIONAL%7B+%0A++++%09%3Fgene+vocab%3Aencodes+%3Fprotein.%0A+++%09%09%3Fprotein+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fprot_lbl.%0A++%09%7D%0A%7D%0A), as far as I know, since the `gene_lbl` is optional it can be ignored, hence, showing results of the rest of the query but it doesn't do so and I don't know why.

Please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Please note that Question EDITs do not result in alerts.  I did not know about your change to your question until just now, when I noticed it by chance.  The reason for the odd results you've described appears to be a bug in the older version of Virtuoso (still in use on the AgroLD endpoint), which has been resolved in more recent versions, which update has already been recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your target endpoint, now [running a 3 year old version](http://volvestre.cirad.fr:8080/agrold/sparqleditor.jsp#query=PREFIX++bif%3A++%3Cbif%3A%3E%0A%0ASELECT%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_dbms_name')++++++++++AS+%3Fname+)%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_dbms_ver')+++++++++++AS+%3Fversion+)%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_build_date')+++++++++AS+%3Fbuild_date+)%0A%0A%23%23+++The+following+line+must+be+commented+for+execution+on+%0A%23%23+++builds+produced+before+the+switch+from+%60cvs%60+to+%60git%60%3B%0A%23%23+++it+only+works+on+versions+later+than+v6.1.5%0A%0A%23+(+bif%3Asys_stat('git_head')++++++++++++++AS+%3Fgit_head+)+++%0A%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_build_thread_model')+AS+%3Fthread+)%0A++(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_build_opsys_id')+++++AS+%3Fopsys+)%0A%0A%23%23+++The+following+two+lines+must+be+commented+for+execution+%0A%23%23+++on+VOS%3B+these+only+work+on+Enterprise+Edition%0A%0A%23+(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_lic_owner')++++++++++AS+%3Fowner+)%0A%23+(+bif%3Asys_stat('st_lic_serial_number')++AS+%3Fserial+)%0A%0AWHERE%0A++%7B++%3Fs++%3Fp++%3Fo++%7D%0ALIMIT+1%0A), should be encouraged to upgrade to the [current Virtuoso Open Source Edition, `07.20.3229` a/k/a `7.2.5.1`](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/stable/7).  Note that both [your original query](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=BASE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.southgreen.fr%2Fagrold%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20vocab%3A%3Cvocabulary%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fgene%20%3Fgene_lbl%20%3Fpathway%20%0D%0AWHERE%7B%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fgene%20%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FBGIOSGA000040%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FSb01g003700.1%3E%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GRAPH%20%3Fgraph1%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fgene%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fgene_lbl.%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GRAPH%20%3Fgraph2%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fgene%20vocab%3Ais_agent_in%20%3Fpathway.%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) and [my revision](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=BASE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.southgreen.fr%2Fagrold%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20vocab%3A%3Cvocabulary%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fgene%20%3Fgene_lbl%20%3Fpathway%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Fgene%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FBGIOSGA000040%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FSb01g003700.1%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fgene%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3Fgene_lbl%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fgene%20%20vocab%3Ais_agent_in%20%20%3Fpathway%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) execute without error on the LOD Cloud Cache (which lacks some of the data in AgroLD, so these don't deliver the results you want).

That said, I think your original query is unnecessarily complex.  Note that [this revision gets results from AgroLD with no problem](http://volvestre.cirad.fr:8080/agrold/sparqleditor.jsp#query=BASE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.southgreen.fr%2Fagrold%2F%3E%0APREFIX+rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX+vocab%3A%3Cvocabulary%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fgene+%3Fgene_lbl+%3Fpathway+%0AWHERE%0A++%7B%0A++++VALUES+%3Fgene+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FBGIOSGA000040%3E+%0A+++++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fidentifiers.org%2Fensembl.plant%2FSb01g003700.1%3E+%7D%0A++++OPTIONAL%7B+%3Fgene++rdfs%3Alabel++%3Fgene_lbl+%7D%0A++++OPTIONAL%7B+%3Fgene++vocab%3Ais_agent_in++%3Fpathway+%7D%0A%7D%0A) --

```
BASE <http://www.southgreen.fr/agrold/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX vocab:<vocabulary/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?gene ?gene_lbl ?pathway 
WHERE
  {
    VALUES ?gene { <http://identifiers.org/ensembl.plant/BGIOSGA000040> 
                   <http://identifiers.org/ensembl.plant/Sb01g003700.1> }
    OPTIONAL{ ?gene  rdfs:label  ?gene_lbl }
    OPTIONAL{ ?gene  vocab:is_agent_in  ?pathway }
}
```